# Car cranks but has trouble starting, runs fine afterwards

Tags: starting, hyundai, cranks-wont-run, accent

The car is a Hyundai Accent 2010 with around 100k km, which I use 2-3 times a week for short trips, and once every 3 months for longer (2+ hour) trips.

For the last two weeks, I had trouble starting my car, it would only start on the second attempt. Yesterday evening I had to try to start it twice, drove to a grocery store, and when I wanted to drive back 15 minutes later it would not start at all. I recorded a video of the behavior, you'll have to raise the volume to hear it properly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkTHaHsIsNI

It either cranks infinitely or cranks a bit then stalls immediately. I called CAA (roadside assistance) and they were able to start it by pressing the gas pedal while turning the key. They connected a device for engine errors but there weren't any. Once it had been started once with the gas pedal, it would start normally afterwards.

When I tried it this morning, it started on the first try, without doing anything special. I'm hesitating taking it to a garage right now since the issue is intermittent, and I would like to try to replace some parts myself before going there. What can I check? The battery is new.

Comment: What do you have as far as diagnostic tools? Swapping parts is hit or miss and a waste of money. I'd check for injector pulse and spark on the no start. Check fuel pressure and volume, then check for possible bleed down at the fuel rail or regulator.

Comment: I do not own any diagnostic tool although my battery charger might be able to display the current. I did replace the spark plugs last year.